# Erroneous MathJax rendering

Tags: bug, mathjax

Look at the words "I am not sure" in the editing window and in the preview in this image. In the editing window they come **after** the expression that is shown following them on the next line in the preview. That happens in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3833283/distribution-likelihood-ratio-given-plr-geq-x-mid-h-2-frac1x).

[image]

Here it is after it is saved:

[image]

Comment: If the problem manifests only in the preview (and not in the actual posts), the it might be useful to add also the ([meta-tag:markdown-preview]) tag.

Comment: @MartinSleziak : But it looks the same after the edit is saved.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification - this wasn't clear from your post. (And I did not manage to reproduce the same behavior - only in the preview.) You might include some details which might possibly influence this to help other users who try to reproduce the problem. (For example, which [MathJax rendrerer](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22647/how-to-change-the-default-mathjax-renderer-on-math-se) you're using, what is the browser and OS, etc.)

Comment: I have managed to find this older post: [Strange behaviour of text following immediately long MathJax expression](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19705). However, it is more than five years old so many changes might have happened since then. (I would not be surprised if there are also some other similar bug reports around.) The problem mentioned in this answer seems similar too: [MathJax v2.5 beta released](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19123#19310). (Again, the post is rather old.)

Comment: For what it's worth, a few months ago, I noticed that *sometimes*, in my longer posts, the `\;` (latex) command, was not working correctly, when imbedded re `$abc \; def$`.  I was never able to reliably reproduce the problem.  When I posted on math.metaSE, someone suggested the `~` command instead.  I switched to that command, and it works.  I suspect, but can not prove, that mathJax on mathSE does not *like* longer posts.  I could **easily be wrong.**